# How to populate a single tournament elimination randomly in PHP without repeat?

Tags: php, arrays, random, tournament

If i have this:

```
$players = array("A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","L","M","N","O","P","Q");
```

How i populate a single tournament elimination like this for example:

```
Matche 1: AxL
Matche 2: CxJ
Matche 3: HxQ
.
.
.
Matche 8: ExP
```

16 players = 8 Matches

I try this and other codes too:

```
<?php

$players = array("A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","L","M","N","O","P","Q");
shuffle ($players);

foreach($players as $key=>$value)
{
    echo $value.','.$value.'<br>';
}

?>
```

Comment: This isn't a code writing service, but if you try writing something you'll probably find some help here.

Comment: [shuffle](http://www.php.net/shuffle) the players array and just assign them 0x1,2x3...

Comment: share your code, what you've tried so far?

Comment: <?php

$players = array("A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","L","M","N","O","P","Q");
shuffle ($players);

foreach($players as $key=>$value)
{
 echo $value.','.$value.'<br>';
}

?>

Comment: I try but many codes does not works correctly

Comment: Sorry guys but today is not a good day for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should work for you:

Just `shuffle()` your array and then `array_chunk()` it into groups of 2, e.g.

```
<?php

    $players = ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","L","M","N","O","P","Q"];
    shuffle($players);
    $players = array_chunk($players, 2);

    foreach($players as $match => $player)
        echo "Match " . ($match+1) . ": " . $player[0] . "x" . $player[1] . "<br>";

?>
```

Comment: how to use with:

array(8) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#4 (2) { ["idPlayer"]=> string(1) "7" ["namePlayer"]=> string(8) "Player 3" } [1]=> object(stdClass)#5 (2)  }

Comment: @DoXuanNguyen And what would be the expected output?

Answer (score 2):

Use the suffle function to randomize the order of the players and read the array by steps of 2

```
shuffle($players);

for ($x = 0; $x < count($players); $x += 2) {
  echo "Match " . (($x/2)+1) . ": " . $players[$x] . "x" . $players[$x+1] . "\n";
}
```